# Secure storage for user data in Outlook

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I need to store some secure data fom my Outlook addin. Is Outlook have sequre storage and how I can access to it by VSTO?

Answer (score 0):

No, Outlook doesn't provide anything for storing the data securely. However, you may consider encrypting your data and then save it in Outlook. For example, you may choose to use a [StorageItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864182.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for that. See [How to: Store Data in a StorageItem for a Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206773%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information. Also you may consider using a user property - see the `UserProperties` property of Outlook items.

In general, all possible options are not restricted by Outlook. You may consider your COM add-in as a regular .Net application so you can use any way you like for storing the data.